# Ext JS 4.2 - Vertical button tooltip issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm facing **vertical** button tooltip issue using Ext JS 4.2 as it's shown at below:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my button configuration:

```
var btnSubmit = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'Giriş',
    iconCls: 'icon-login',
    tooltip: '<b>Sisteme giriş yapmak için</b> tıklayınız...[<b><i>Enter</i></b>]'    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use overide css for tooltip class.

```
.x-tip {width: auto !important;}
.x-tip-body {width: auto !important;}
.x-tip-body span {width: auto !important;}
```